# java web application ui framework

Tags: java, jquery-ui, user-interface, wicket

any idea what kind of UI framework have been used for the following website?

[https://www.paytm.com/][1]

I prefer to use such UI framework in java web application. If you are familiar, please let me know.

Comment: jQuery on the front-end... are you interested in knowing the back-end? why?

Comment: no..not interested to know..just wanted to know the UI framework thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using [Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as you can see by the source.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery on the front end, [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) for a transport between front end and back end; what's exactly within the back end, really hard to say from the headers.